# when multi writers access the shared data concurrently,what's the sequence of them

Tags: linux, multithreading, data-synchronization

I'm learning synchronization knowledge of linux. Now I have a question. When mutiple write threads(or processes) want to change the shared data concurrently, I would use mutex(or other lock) to ensure that there is just only one writer at the same time. Which writer is the first one having the privilege to change the shared data.

Comment: Whoever gets scheduled first. With a single mutex you cannot enforce ordering.

Comment: @Arash Thx. But I still have some confusion. If those threads have the same priority, and contend the access at the same time on multi-core architecture, who is the first?

Comment: As I said, there is no ordering that we can make an assumption on. When they are created they are added to the ready queue to get CPU time (in the ready queue there are all processes that are runnable in the whole system, not only your application). It depends on the CPU scheduler to assign them to which core and the length of the runnable queue on that core and ...